# How to check if array of objects has same value for same key?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of object ,wanted to check the key "PhysicalVirtual" has same value in all objects.
if it has same value, should return `true` else it should return `false`.

code which I have tried:

```
var testArray=[{
    "Hostname": "NDCWCAP03",   
    "PhysicalVirtual": "P",
    "Tier1": null,
    "Tier3": null,    
}, {
    "Hostname": "NDCWCAP05",
    "PhysicalVirtual": "P",
    "Tier1": null,
    "Tier3": null,    
}];

gs.info(testArray.find(key => key.PhysicalVirtual === 'P'));
```

Error: getting syntax error here

```
Evaluator: com.glide.script.RhinoEcmaError: syntax error
   script : Line(13) column(30)
console.log(testArray.find(key => key.PhysicalVirtual === 'P'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.every()`

```js
let testArray = [{Hostname:"NDCWCAP03",PhysicalVirtual:"P",Tier1:null,Tier3:null},{Hostname:"NDCWCAP05",PhysicalVirtual:"P",Tier1:null,Tier3:null}];

let PV1 = testArray[0].PhysicalVirtual
let allMatch = testArray.every(obj => obj.PhysicalVirtual === PV1)
console.log(allMatch)
```

Edit: Without `Array.every()`

```js
var testArray = [{Hostname:"NDCWCAP03",PhysicalVirtual:"P",Tier1:null,Tier3:null},{Hostname:"NDCWCAP05",PhysicalVirtual:"P",Tier1:null,Tier3:null}];

var PV1 = testArray[0].PhysicalVirtual;
var allMatch = true;
for(var i=0; i<testArray.length; i++){
  if(testArray[i].PhysicalVirtual !== PV1){
    allMatch = false;
    break;
  }
}
console.log(allMatch)
```

Comment: am using this code servicenow widget  `let` is not supported .getting this error : `Evaluator: com.glide.script.RhinoEcmaError: let is an ECMAScript 6 feature - not supported`

Comment: is there any alternative for `let`

Comment: I tried with `var` its not working.I think `every` is not supported in servicenow.

Comment: @krish you can do the same with a for loop and a Boolean, just a little more complicated. I don’t have time now but if I remember I will revise my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `every` method of `arrays` to test a condition in all its members like:

```
const isTrue = testArray.every(
  ({ PhysicalVirtual }) => PhysicalVirtual === testArray[0].PhysicalVirtual
);

console.log(isTrue)
>>> True
```

Comment: am using this code in servicenow,I think `every` is not supported in servicenow.can you pls let me know any alternavtive?

Answer (score 1):

JS [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) is best solution for this

```js
var testArray=[{
    "Hostname": "NDCWCAP03",   
    "PhysicalVirtual": "P",
    "Tier1": null,
    "Tier3": null,    
}, {
    "Hostname": "NDCWCAP05",
    "PhysicalVirtual": "P",
    "Tier1": null,
    "Tier3": null,    
}];

//ES6
//let PhysicalVirtualValue = testArray[0]?.PhysicalVirtual;
//let hasValue = false;
//if (testArray.length)
//  hasValue = testArray.every( e=> e.PhysicalVirtual == PhysicalVirtualValue);

//console.log(hasValue);

//without Array.every
var PhysicalVirtualValue = testArray[0]? testArray[0].PhysicalVirtual : '';
var hasValue = true;
for(var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {

  if (testArray[i].PhysicalVirtual != PhysicalVirtualValue){
    hasValue = false;
    break;
  }    
}


console.log(hasValue);
```

Comment: am using this code in servicenow,I think `every` is not supported in servicenow.can you pls let me know any alternavtive?